# How can I split a dataset between two matrix controls in SSRS 2005

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

In SSRS 2005, is there a way I can create two side by side tables of 6 rows each so that each table (or Matrix) has a portion of the same data set?

Here is the query I'm using for the dataset.

```
Select 
Equipment_EquipmentID,
Equipment_Description,
Vendor,
Operator,
JobAccount_TrackingID
from 
(
Select row_number() over (partition by Equipment_EquipmentID order by JobAccount_TrackingID) row,*
from 
(
SELECT DISTINCT
CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount_1.Equipment_EquipmentID, 
CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount_1.Equipment_Description, 
NULL as Vendor, 
NULL as Operator,
CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount_1.JobAccount_TrackingID
FROM
CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount AS CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount_1 INNER JOIN CustomizedAccount ON CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount_1.Account_AccountID = CustomizedAccount.AccountID
WHERE
(CustomizedAccount.AppliesToEquipment = 1)
AND 
(CustomizedFieldLogEquipmentJobAccount_1.FieldLog_FieldLogID =@FieldLogID)
--AND
--IsRented = 0
Union
Select Distinct 
Equipment_EquipmentID,
Equipment_Description,
Null as Vendior,
NULL as Operator,
fake_TrackingID

FROM
CustomizedFieldLogEquipment

cross join
(
Select 'zzz01' fake_TrackingID
union Select 'zzz02' 
union Select 'zzz03' 
union Select 'zzz04' 
union Select 'zzz05' 
union Select 'zzz06' 
union Select 'zzz07' 
union Select 'zzz08' 
union Select 'zzz09' 
union Select 'zzz10' 
) a where FieldLog_FieldLogID = @FieldLogID --AND IsRented = 0
) b 
) c where Row<=6
order by Equipment_EquipmentID,JobAccount_TrackingID
```

The TrackingiD is the column in my Matrix and I need to show a total of 6 columns weather or not there is data in there (Hence the fake TrackingIds) the query works great. But I need to be able to split the results of the query between two matrix controls in the report if the rowcount  is greater than 6. 
In essence I need 2 6x6 tables. The way it needs to work is strange. If the query results return more than 6 rows, the users want the rest of the records to flow over to the 2nd table. Kind of like the illustration below:

From this:

[image: current Version]

To this:

[image: New concept]

I've already gotten the two matrix controls on the form, but can't figure out how to split the dataset between two tables like that if the row count is larger than 7 or so.

Is this possible? If so how? I've done some searching, but can't figure out how to split a single recordset into two matrix controls. Any help is appreciated. I keep trying to tell the users that this is not a form printing program but a program designed to report what is in the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a RowNumber column to your dataset.

Then [add a filter to each matrix control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156270%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). The first matrix should filter for rows with RowNumber between 1-6, and the second matrix would filter for 7-12.

Admittedly, this is a quick and dirty way. The report itself however is outside the intended use of SSRS, so I don't know if it's really worth worrying about how you get the matrices to split, as long as there aren't any performance issues.

This seems so limiting and inflexible. Are the users really sure they only want x number of rows, forever? If they ever change the number of rows, you're the victim who has to make changes to the report to accommodate.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. The report is not a true report as we think of it, but more of a time sheet that has some minimal info filled in then gets faxed to the crew in the field for them to fill out and fax back in. So we are redesigning the time sheet from crystal reports to SSRS, and in doing so making some "enhancements".

it's really more of a job for a forms application and I've had to jump through some hoops to get the formatting as they want it. for example a specific number of columns and rows weather or not there are records for that so the field can hand write any changes in.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that is going to work. In my query, I am creating fake columns so each EquipmentID record gets duplicated 6 times (once for each of the columns needed) so the row number for the 1st record will be from 1-6 and the 2nd from 7-12 etc....

Do you know of a way around this?

Comment: I did get it to work by filtering the 1st matrix by any row between 1 and 36 (rows multiplied by number of groupings) and matrix2 filtered between 37 and 62. But a strange issue has popped up. matrix2 is now showing one extra blank column.

the dataset is the same for both tables in fact they are duplicates except for the filtering. any idea why this would happen?